# Add a button to a view

Tags: android, button, layout

I have managed to successfully create an always on top view using the following method:

```
s_translucentView = new View(this);


s_BrightnessParams = new android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams(-1,getDisplayHeight(),0,0,    
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                        |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR 
                        |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

wm.addView(s_translucentView, s_translucentParams);
```

Now what I wish to do is to add a Relative layout to s_translucentView and subsequently, add a Button into the layout.  Is there anyway of doing this?

An icing on the cake would be if someone could show me how to react to the button press!

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use XML for your layout? It's much simpler.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but can I add the XML to my s_translucentView?  thanks... (I need that view because its serving other functions...)

Comment: First of all you cannot add anything to an instance of `View`, you must use a subclass of `ViewGroup`. And [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#write) shows you how to use XML layouts (if you haven't used xml layouts before).

Comment: Can I make a Layout always on top?  Rather like I have done with the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your view is empty and you wish to add a RelativeLayout I suggest change your view into a RelativeLayout such as so, (not effective to place a relativelayout inside an empty view)

```
RelativeLayout s_translucentView = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

For the button you create and add action with

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

You can also create the button Params like so

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams();
```

Then to add the button to the view do this

```
s_translucentView.addView(btn, lp);
```

Comment: Do you require anything else for the answer to be marked correct?